# Add block in <head> tag in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I want to add block in  tag. I dont want to add this script in `Configuration > HTML Head >  Scripts and Style Sheets`. Please check attached screenshot.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="after.body.start">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Js\Components" name="frontuser" as="frontuser" template="Frontuser_Tags::frontuser/tags.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

[image]

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Replace this following code in your **Layout Xml**. This will work for you.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="head.additional">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="frontuser" template="Frontuser_Tags::frontuser/tags.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: not working for me in m2.3.2

Comment: <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="head.additional">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="help" template="Sample_Help::help.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>

Comment: Not working for me , when i use the head.additional then the template is rendering in the body tag always , not sure what i am missing here

Answer (score 5):

Use

`<referenceBlock name="head.additional">`

Instead of

`<referenceContainer name="after.body.start">`